# XAML WPF stack panel leaves too much empty space before and after MenuItem

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Hello I have created a e simple menu. When I press on a menu item it expands to reveal additional options. As you can see from the screenshot attached there is too much space before and after the controls and there is this annoying white border that I can't get rid of.

[image: menu]

Bellow is a sniping of the XAML code I have for the menu item  stile and how i have put sub menues.

This is the code for the style

```
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">

            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="white"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1E1E1E"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>


            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFBDF9F9"/>
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>
```

This is the code for the sub menu

```
        <Menu VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" RenderTransformOrigin="0.499,-5.554" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="780">
            <MenuItem x:Name="menuFile" Header="File">
                <MenuItem x:Name="menu_Exit"  Header="Exit" Click="menu_Exit_Click"/>
            </MenuItem>

            <MenuItem x:Name="menuPriceListOptions" Header="Price List Options" >

                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <MenuItem x:Name="menu_VewPrices" Header="Vew Prices" Click="menu_VewPrices_Click" />
                    <MenuItem x:Name ="menu_ImportPricesFromFile" Header="Import Prices From File" Click="menu_ImportPricesFromFile_Click" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Import Prices Manualy" />
                </StackPanel>
                
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
```

Comment: Why the StackPanel? Just add the MenuItems. Then the menu will look as expected

Comment: BionicCode I read that the proper way to do it is to use stack panel. If I remove it it still works as expected but the white border is still present

Comment: You should use Microsoft Docs and the API browser as your primary source of knowledge. There are way too many bad tutorials out there. For example take a look at [Menu Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/menu-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to learn the basics about the Menu.

Comment: The menu is a nested item view. When you click on the top level item like Price List Options, you open a huge item that contains all the child items. Since you have set the Padding to 2, you have effectively added a border with a width of 2 around the child items. Remove the padding - at least from the top level item. Then apply the style explicitly to each item if you want to add the Padding to those particular items. I don't think the padding is needed, for any item of the menu, but i don't know how you want the final result to look like.

Comment: @BionicCode Specifying the style for each item fixed the issue with the border. The padding was there for unknown reasons but it didn't really do anything. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you want to style the MenuItem to change the layout, you should consider to override the default template(s): [Menu and MenuItem ControlTemplate Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/menu-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#menu-and-menuitem-controltemplate-example). This way you can target e.g. submenu items exclusively (by using the proper template key like `x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}"`).